# Numpy keep dimensions globally

Tags: python, numpy

Currently, most numpy functions drop singleton dimensions automatically, and to keep them, one needs to memorize various arguments such as `keepdims=True` or `np.newaxis`. I was wondering if there has been (or will be) a global setting for that because I am writing a program that needs to keep dimensions all the time. My ideal code would be like

```
import numpy as np
np.setparams(keepdims=True)  # anything like this?

x = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 10))
np.sum(x, axis=0).shape  # prints (1, 10)
x[:, 0].shape  # prints (5, 1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: As useful as it would be, I don't think so.  Those of us who do high-dimensional math with `numpy` just learn to always use `keepdims` and enclose singleton coordinates in brackets (i.e. `x[:, [0]]`

Comment: @DanielF I appreciate your comment. However, I teach first-year students linear algebra and ask them to use Numpy. They find it frustrating to remember the arguments. Sometimes they forget about it, and Python could occupy the whole memory trying to create a 1M x 1M matrix, for example.

Comment: Sounds like you want the MATLAB behavior of keeping a minimum of 2 dimensions.  It can still reduce a 3d to 2d.  If cost is an issue, try Octave.

Comment: But even with MATLAB keeping track of dimensions is a big part of debugging. A (1,5) shape can mess up broadcasting just as easily as a (5,).  Broadcasting may be the problem here, not dropped dimensions.

Comment: Back in the early days of `numpy`, they added a `matrix` subclass, which fixes the dimension at 2.  That matched, more or less, the 1990s version of MATLAB.  But generally we discourage its use, feeling it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the comments and the nice touch on the history part. I find the `matrix` subclass nice to work with. I would like the students to remember the importance of dimensions, and the 1D-array is just not a math thing, IMO.

Comment: I just looked at my undergraduate linear algebra book.  It has equations like `z_i = sum_j  a_ij * x_j + y_i`, which in `numpy` could expressed as `z = np.einsum('ij,j->i', A, x) + y` or `z = A.dot(x)+y`.  I've studied enough different types of math and computer languages that I'm comfortable with both the MATLAB style and numpy one.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the numpy version you are dealing with, something you can do is study the signature of the function of interest, presently [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), locate the default value within `numpy.sum._implementation.__defaults__`, and turn it as you wish.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> np.sum(a)
10
>>> (defaults := numpy.sum._implementation.__defaults__)
(None, None, None, False, <no value>, <no value>)
#                  ^^^^^
>>> numpy.sum._implementation.__defaults__ = (defaults[:3], True, defaults[4:])
>>> np.sum(a)
array([10])
```

Which solution does not impact [`numpy.ndarray.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) though.

```
>>> a.sum()
10
```